# SIM900: How to be sure how much time to wait between serial(UART) transmit and receive

Tags: gcc, avr, uart, sim900

---

i have written a library in C for using the SIM900 GSM with my uC but it has many many bugs. Sometimes it works sometimes not. My hardware works fine I think.

I rewrote it and made sure that the basic functions are bug free.

- SIM900_transmit( char* );
- SIM900_reveive( char** );
- SIM900_on();
- SIM900_off();

Now I want to write the **SIM900_command** function that will use **SIM900_transmit**( char* ) and **SIM900_reveive**( char** );

### So my detailed question is:

How to know how much time to wait between AT command and receiving the answer from SIM900. I do not want to just put _delay_ms(1000).

Thanks in advance...

Comment: This is on-topic at [electronics.SE] as it is based around the timing specifications of a piece of hardware.

Comment: If it's communicating over UART you simply wait until a character is available at the interface.

Comment: I do this inside SIM900_receive( char**); Am I good?

It is something like:


<pre>
    if(uart_available>0)
    {
        //Code to receive here....
    }

</pre>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, you wait until a character is available and then receive it. Have a look [here](http://maxembedded.com/2013/09/the-usart-of-the-avr/#TxRxUART). There you have for AVR devices with a single UART:

```
unsigned char uart_recieve (void)
{
    while(!(UCSRA) & (1<<RXC));
    return UDR;
}
```

So, with `while(!(UCSRA) & (1<<RXC));` you basically block execution until there is a character available at the uart.

Comment: What you said is inside uart_available in some other form. I used it and it works. Thank you. It was helpful and made me look in the right direction.

Comment: It said I can mark my own answer as correct in two days... I will try to remember and do this. Your answer also is good. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I found my main problem. Now I will fix the old SIM900 library.

### OLD CODE:

```
/*
 * Sent the AT command.
 */
softuart_puts_P( "Transmit" );
SIM900_transmit( "AT\r" );
softuart_puts_P( " completed\r\n" );

/*
 * Wait until SIM900 answers back.
 */
while ( uart_available() == 0 )//BUG: Loop in a loop(receive has one) caused chaos.
{   
    /*
     * Sent the AT command.
     */
    softuart_puts_P( "Received: [" );
    cString answer = newEmptyString();
    SIM900_receive( &answer );
    softuart_puts( answer );
    softuart_puts_P( "]\r\n" );
    deleteString( &answer );
}
```

### NEW CODE

```
/*
 * Sent the AT command.
 */
softuart_puts_P( "Transmit" );
SIM900_transmit( "AT\r" );
softuart_puts_P( " completed\r\n" );

/*
 * Wait until SIM900 answers back.
 */
while ( uart_available() == 0 );// TODO: Put timeout in case SIM900 is switched off.

/*
 * Sent the AT command.
 */
softuart_puts_P( "Received: [" );
cString answer = newEmptyString();
SIM900_receive( &answer );
softuart_puts( answer );
softuart_puts_P( "]\r\n" );
deleteString( &answer );
```

This does the work: ***while ( uart_available() == 0 );***

Thanks for your help.